# Javascript :: live replace() with regex, only when a word 'terminates'

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i want to replace every occurrence of a word in a string as it is typed,

here's what i've got taken out of context...

```
$(document).on('keyup','textarea', function() {
    this.value=this.value.replace(/\bnot\b$/gi,"_-Ni!-_ ");
});
```

so this will replace the word 'not' every time you type it into a textarea,

i used the regex to avoid replacing 'not' in words like 'another',

the problem i am having now is that the function replaces words that start with not if you are a slower typer than the script running,

so words like 'noteworthy', get changed before one can type the 'eworthy',

i thought to specify each possible ending word scenario, such as new lines, spaces, punctuation et al, but i instead looked if there was an easier way and was unable to find one, so before i tackd a slue of special characters onto the back of the word i thought i'd ask the community if they knew a way

Comment: You could do `\bnot(?=\W$)` and replace with `_-Ni!-_`. That would wait for one more character to be typed, and then only do the replacement if that character ended the word.

Comment: I would suggest replacing on blur rather than on keyup anyways

Comment: classic, i implemented it and did some quick QA... 'not_' is ignored, interesting ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp... but this is the best i've got, thanks a lot

Comment: @Peregrine that's because, in regex, word characters are letters digits and underscores. See my answer.

Comment: yeah i dig, i read why in the doc, it just seems interesting to me that underscores are even considered 'word characters'

Comment: i hear the .on('blur', suggestion it just changes the feel of the implementation... it is meant to alert your train of thought, stead act like a spell check function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that the `not` is a full word, you need to wait for one more character and make sure that it's not a word character:

```
(document).on('keyup','textarea', function() {
    this.value=this.value.replace(/\bnot(?=\W$)/gi, "_-Ni!-_ ");
});
```

Note that both `\w`, `\W` and `\b` understand "word characters" as letters, digits and underscores. If you want *only* letters, you need to change it like so:

```
/\bnot(?=[^a-z]$)/gi
```

For the beginning of the word, you'll need to work a bit harder, because lookbehinds are not part of the ECMAScript regex flavor:

```
/(^|[^a-z])not(?=[^a-z]$)/gi
```

And replace with

```
"$1_-Ni!-_ "
```

Which writes back the previous character.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/\bnot\b\s
```

"\s" refers to whitespace. This will only match the word "not" by itself.

Comment: i'm also interested in punctation 'not.' should be replaced

Comment: the second `\b` is redundant. There's always a word boundary between a `t` and the following whitespace.